# reCAPTCHA Integration Without Reference to External API

Tags: recaptcha

Does google have a way to reference their reCAPTCHA JavaScript API without adding an external link?

I want to integrate the "I'm not a robot" checkbox on our site but I have to adhere to security requirements that all JavaScript on the page originates from our server. So this line is a problem:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

I've looked all over the documentation, I can't find any downloadable package or custom API for implementation. I would download the js file, but there's no mechanism for making sure it's up to date and I'm pretty sure it would break things anyway. Is any way to get around this requirement?